# I'm fist at QT creator, I am trying to config a project on QT, but it failed

Tags: macos, qt, cmake

My OS is Mac and I am trying to config a project from https://github.com/MITK/MITK

but when I tried to config the source code in QT, errors occured. this is the mistake message:

/Users/cjz/CCode/MITK/CMakeLists.txt:22: error: No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found. Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment variable "CXX" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER to the full path to the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.

I am a fresh guy on QT and CMake, anyone helps me?
thank you.

Comment: you need to install Xcode and Xcode command line tools. Than you have to start Xcode to accept license agreement, than Qt Creator will be able to use tool chain which is shipped with Xcode.

Comment: I have installed Xcode before installing QT and accepted the liense and agreement, but the problem remained the same.

Comment: and how about command line tools?

Comment: OK, I will try, I thought that command line is part of the Xcode--

Comment: I have installed Xcode in apple store, so i think the xcode command line tools are already installed.

Comment: they are part of Xcode, but not installed by default. [Try this](http://railsapps.github.io/xcode-command-line-tools.html) or [google something else](https://www.google.com/search?q=xcode+command+line+tools+installation).

Comment: @chengjunzhang open Terminal and type `sudo xcode-select --install`

Comment: @chengjunzhang Firstly, you have to launch xcode at least once. Secondly, you have to choose the CLT version in it.

Comment: I ran this on my terminal and it said that command line tools are already installed.                                                                                                          :  cjdeMacBook-Pro:~ cjz$ sudo xcode-select --install
Password:
xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates

Comment: I tried following command:

Comment: cjdeMacBook-Pro:~ cjz$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

Comment: cjdeMacBook-Pro:~ cjz$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Comment: @light2yellow  I suppose that I have installed xcode and xcode command line, but the problem remains the same--~~~~(>_<)~~~~

Comment: Please read my comment once again. I do not tell you to _install_ CLT.